# Run Golang project with multiple files on Goland

Tags: go, goland

I'm new to the Go language and have a problem when I'm trying to run a simple project which contains two files, on Goland IDE.

The first file called `main` -

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    card := list{0, add(0)}
    cards := append(card, add(3))
    cards = append(card, add(4))

    for i, c := range cards {
        fmt.Println(i, c)
    }
}

func add(x int) int {
    return x + 1
}
```

And the second file called list -

```
package main
type list []int
```

When I'm trying to use the second file from the first file (use list type) I get `compilation failed` and -

```
command-line-arguments
.\main.go:6:10: undefined: list
```

What have I missed?

Comment: try "go run main.go list.go" 
or build the project first and then run it

Comment: There is a simple and convenient way to do that kind of thing (in case I deal with a project which includes a lot of files) from JetBrain Goland IDE?

Comment: there is, however I am currently not at my laptop. will give an answer with screenshots later in the day.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it, the Package option should be chosen instead of the File option -

[image]

Comment: just came home. yes, that's exactly what I wanted to show you.

Comment: this's work for me